# Unable to start or upgrade network using Hyperledger Composer 0.19

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

since the recent upgrade I have trouble to start or deploy changes on my network. The commands : composer network start and composer network upgrade both give me this error message:

Error: Error trying to upgrade business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT

I saw several posts with the same problem but no clear solution. The same thing is happening on the Playground UI when I want to deploy changes. I verified that I'm not behind a proxy or else. Thanks

Comment: If you are using Composer v0.19.0, have you upgraded Fabric to v1.1 GA? Is you Fabric started?

Comment: Yep, Fabric is upgraded to 1.1 and launched. The composer network start command worked one time, but I still have connection issues when I want to upgrade or to start Playground.

Comment: I can confirm this problem and I am using v 0.19.1 on my virtual machine..
There is some proposed workaround suggested [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3731), but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your peer is on by running `docker ps`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It is running, as well as the other containers. I tried again using another wifi connection and it worked well. However, I'm still stuck using my normal connection. Apparently, the problem is that since the update, composer network start commands use a npm install, which create the issue. If anyone have a solution to resolve this (other than switch between internet networks) it would be great !

Comment: If it works/doesn't work depending on a connection, then your problem is not with composer. Perhaps you have some ports blocked on one of your connection, or your router somehow messes with the payload?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `docker ps` list, make sure that there is no same version running to which you are upgrading. If so exist, delete it using

```
> docker stop containerId

> docker rm containerId
```

also before creating the archive file do not forget to set new version in package.json or you will get error like:

> `Error trying install business network. Error: The business network
>   is already installed on all the peers`